# iPhone app with local HTML file doesn't support link

Tags: iphone, html, web-applications, local

I want to create simple iPhone app with local HTML file.

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile];
[waWebView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

I made one webView and make it show index.html file in same directory with .m file.
Then make an another HTML file; index2.html, in same directory
I want to see index2.html through a link in index.html

So, in index.html,  I put

```
<a href="index2.html">View html 2</a>
```

index.html is successfully shown, but **above link doesn't work**.
**What do I need more? Help meT.T**

In additional to this problem, this app **doesn't support javascript** code too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the link is relativ.. you need to set the baseURL of your webView to the path containing the index html file

```
NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *base = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:file.stringByRemovingLastPathComponent];
[webview loadHTMLString:text baseURL:base];
```

Comment: I tried this approach using the path to the html file, but it didn't work so I switched to using NSURLRequest. However I missed off the stringByRemovingLastPathComponent part. This makes sense because the 'base url' should be a folder, not a file path. Thanks for that!

Comment: Thank you for your help!!<br>The only question is... I think 'text' should be html code itself and that 'text' code will be shown on webview. Then if I want to see 'index.html' at the beginning of app, is 'text' supposed to be 'index.html' code itself???<br> starting with `<!doctype html><html><head> ...`

Answer (score 0):

It is done by creating a NSURL using its fileURLWithPath and then a NSURLRequest and loading that rather loading the html itself:

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlFile];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[waWebView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: that does the same as my answer as it implicitly sets the baseurl too :) this is better but not as explicit and doesnt explain the underlying prob IMHO .. I;d look at mine for an explanation and then go on to this one!

Answer (score -1):

You may need to add javascript to it for it to work. If you want to make a simple iPhone app just use app mobi(http://www.appmobi.com/) and they let you put css html and js files into a builder and it does the magic for you. Try that.

Hope I Helped

LucaSpeedStack